# How do multimedia players calculate framerate?

Tags: windows, winapi, timer, multimedia

What are some common or unusual ways that multimedia players like wmplayer.exe, realplayer.exe and vlc.exe use to calculate frame rate? I have read in some books that multimedia players usually rely on windows api like timeGetTime, QueryPerformanceCount, GeTickCount to calculate frame rate but is it practical to use SetTimer to do it? If not, what others ways do they use to calculate frame rate? I want to write universal playback speed controller for these players but not sure how wmplayer or realplayer does it.

p.s: I found out through trial and error that vlc.exe uses timeGetTime().

Comment: Are you trying to intercept API calls and return fake results to control the media players' playback speed?

Comment: @IInspectable: Yes, something like that.

Comment: _"universal playback speed controller"_ - it's either called _"use proper source material so you don't have to fake the framerate"_ or _"use the player's APIs"_. Explain **what** you are trying to do and **why**, so more accurate suggestions can be given.

Answer (score 1):

Players that stream media content don't normally need to calculate frame rate because it is defined by the input signal. Video input is typically a stream of timestamped video frames and the player's responsibility is to present an individual video frame right on time.

There is no frame rate in this equation, the player needs to match an individual frame time to current clock time. Reference clock might be either system time, or hardware device clock. It is typical to use audio output device as a reference clock, or video output device (if it is not a display).

If the input rate is variable or you otherwise want to get effective presentation frame rate, you don't need much of an accuracy for this because all you want is a running average of frames presented during last N seconds (`GetTickCount` accurancy is more than sufficient for this, no need in `timeGetTime` even though its use is okay as well; `QueryPerformanceCounter` is going to give the worst accuracy because it is not designed/expected to stay exactly realtime on long time intervals).

Comment: "... the player's responsibility is to present an individual video frame right on time" How does the player achieve this then? How does it make sure that each frame is display right on time. I would imagine there there must be some kind of time function involved. Is SetTimer good enough for this kind of task?

Comment: There is no specific function, and methods can actually vary. A typical, yet no the only way, is to look at current time on audio playback device and use it as a reference. There is no straight API function for this (such as for hooking) though.

Comment: And how does the audio playback device keep track of the time? This seems like chicken and egg problem now.

Comment: There is no problem, you didn't explain any. _"How do video players time their playback"_ is an implementation detail. You seem to have a problem that might have something to do with playback speed, but faking the computer time for the player is most likely not going to fix that.

Comment: There is no chicken/egg question. Player uses reference time source at its own discretion. There is no specific function. Having this clock as a reference it then matches frames onto the clock time to schedule presentation.

Comment: Basically it's up to the implementation of the media player what it uses to keep track of time. It doesn't have to be an api (hidden api?) but it definitely has to use something to keep track of time to make sure the frames are displayed on time.